# Are there potential drawbacks to using a [weak self] within a closure after declaring a strong self?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, weak-references

The title I used for this may not be particularly clear, so I hope that a working code sample can provide some clarity.

The issue I am facing is that I have a scenario similar to the code below:

```
import Foundation

class Test {
    private var isInner = false {
        didSet {
            print("isInner: \(isInner)")
        }
    }

    private func runClosure(closure: () -> ()) {
        closure()
    }

    func callClosure() {
        // Weak 1
        runClosure { [weak self] in
            self?.isInner = false
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            // Can this [weak self] create problems?
            // Weak 2
            strongSelf.runClosure { [weak self] in
                self?.isInner = true
            }
        }
    }
}

let test = Test()
test.callClosure()
// The following is printed to the console
// isInner: false
// isInner: true
```

Everything above works precisely as intended, which is good.

My concern is the second use of `[weak self]`. While `self` is declared weak at the start of the function (**Weak1**), I then set it to `strongSelf` shortly thereafter.

I could re-use my earlier `strongSelf`, but the functions in question are actually potentially long running operations and there exists the possibility that self could be out of scope between **Weak1** and **Weak2**.

However, it has been brought to my attention that the potential exists for `Weak2` to be invalid, which is what I am hoping to clarify with this question.

Ultimately, all that weak does is create an optional variable for self, so I am not aware of any potential pitfalls. Additionally, **Weakself1**, `strongSelf`, and **Weakself2** are all pointing at the same memory address during the execution of `callClosure()`.

Comment: In your example the *weak - strong* dance is pointless as the closure does not cause a retain cycle.

Comment: Thanks @vadian, that was one of my thoughts coming out of this. My original intention with the second weak was just an abundance of caution, but if there is no point to it then I'm happy to drop it.

Comment: Everything in your example runs synchronous, so the `weak`/`strong` are not needed since the object won't get a chance to deallocate anyway.

Comment: Yes, but I did not feel like replicating proprietary production code into my question. I do mention farther down that the real operations can be long running.

Comment: What exactly is your concern?  Assuming that `runClosure` completes asynchronously in your real code, when then outer closure completes, the strong reference held by `strongSelf` will be released.  There is a chance that when the second closure is invoked that the second `weak self` will be `nil` if `self` has been deallocated by that point, but you check for this with the optional unwrap. It can't be "invalid".  It either references `self` or it is `nil`

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks, it is a bit difficult to clarify specifically what "invalid" is since I was not given anything specific. My assumption here was at worst, it was pointless as @vadian pointed out. My objective with this question was to find out if I was simply missing something in this particular scenario, and using the second `[weak self]` was truly a bad thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take this step by step (line by line)

```
// Weak 1
runClosure { [weak self] in
```

The first line creates a reference to the target object, a reference which coincidentally (or not) is named `self`.

```
    self?.isInner = false
```

The above line makes use of the weak reference, it has no effects on the target object lifecycle.

```
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
```

Now, this line indeed creates a strong reference to the target object, which will extend objects's lifetime by at least the lifetime of `strongSelf`. Now depending on the compiler aggressiveness, `strongSelf` might die after passing this line (the last reference in code), or when the outer closure finishes executing.

```
    // Can this [weak self] create problems?
    // Weak 2
    strongSelf.runClosure { [weak self] in
```

Now this has almost exactly the same effect as the capture from the outer closure. It creates a reference to a possibly already deallocated instance (depending if `strongSelf` is still alive at this point or not).

```
            self?.isInner = true
```

This is the regular optional usage, no effects on target lifetime.

Now, assuming that `runClosure` runs asynchronously, there are no issues with the target object living more that expected (assuming there aren't any more strong references out there).

To summarize, an object lifetime is determined by the number of strong references exist to that object. Once all strong references are destroyed, the object will be automatically deallocated. In your particular scenario, the inner closure weakly captures and already weak reference, and this doesn't impact the lifecycle of the target object. The only player is `strongSelf`, which gets destroyed no later than the outer closure destroyal.